# could not create a view primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_slice_op

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, intel-mkl

This question is an extension to [A 'Concatenate' layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842712/a-concatenate-layer-should-be-called-on-a-list-of-at-least-2-inputs/59843479#59843479). Please read that first.

I am now receiving the above error when using multiple 
op 'layers'. Strangely, my code works when I use just 1 op 
 'layer', and I don't know why.

Code:

```
#Import statements
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers as L
from collections import deque
from scipy.special import spence

#Op and conv functions
def op(x, units, kernel, stride, activation):
    x_list = []
    for i in range(units):
        x_list.append(L.Conv2D(1, kernel, stride, activation=activation)(x))
    x = L.Concatenate(-1)(x_list)

    return x

def conv(x, units, kernel, stride, activation):
    x = L.Conv2D(units, kernel, stride, activation=activation)(x)
    return x

#Build_model function
    def build_model(self):
        inputx = L.Input(shape=self.state_size)
        goalx = L.Input(shape=self.state_size)
        x = L.Concatenate(-1)([goalx, inputx])
        x = conv(x, 4, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 4, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 4, (5,5), (2,2), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 4, (5,5), (2,2), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 4, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 2, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 2, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = op(x, 2, (5,5), (1,1), activation=swish)
        x = L.Flatten()(x)
        outp = L.Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax')(x)
        valp = L.Dense(1)(x)
        model = keras.models.Model([inputx, goalx], outp)
        critic = keras.models.Model([inputx, goalx], valp)
        model.compile(loss='msle', optimizer='adam')
        critic.compile(loss='msle', optimizer='adam')
        return model, critic
```

Traceback:

```
2020-01-22 00:12:23.373959: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at mkl_slice_op.cc:436 : Aborted: Operation received an exception:Status: 5, message: could not create a view primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_slice_op.cc:433
2020-01-22 00:12:23.374013: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Aborted: Operation received an exception:Status: 5, message: could not create a view primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_slice_op.cc:433
     [[{{node Slice_3}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thoughtform.py", line 76, in <module>
    main_loop()
  File "thoughtform.py", line 70, in main_loop
    dqn.replay(1)
  File "/home/ai/Projects/Thoughtforms/dqn.py", line 75, in replay
    self.model.fit(state, advantage, epochs=1, verbose=0)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 324, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py", line 86, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 520, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1141, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError:  Operation received an exception:Status: 5, message: could not create a view primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_slice_op.cc:433
     [[node Slice_3 (defined at /home/ai/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_4600]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error. I installed mkl and updated tensorflow to 2.1.0 which solved the issue.